# Adding Special Characters to a plot in R

Tags: r

I need to add a special character to a plot in R. The character that I need to add is the letter 'o' with a dash over it (ō). How can I do this? If I wanted to add the character μ to my plot (as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736370/special-characters-and-superscripts-r-plot-axis-titles)), I can type "mu". But what do I type for o-bar (I'm wishing for a repository of special characters in R)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [special characters and superscripts R plot axis titles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736370/special-characters-and-superscripts-r-plot-axis-titles)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try combining expression with the `bar` function

```
plot(1:5,main = expression("This is your Special Character -" ~ bar(o)))
```

[image: Plot 1]

Just to add a little more information, R actually lets you do a lot of cool stuff with plotting symbols. check out `?bar`.

Just some examples you can try by replacing your argument in main, xlab or ylab:

`main = expression(sum(x[i], i==1, n))`

`main = expression(integral(f(x)*dx, a, b))`

Comment: Excellent, `bar` is exactly what I was looking for.