# Rstudio - Writing superscript on axis

Tags: r, axis, superscript

I'm trying to write the follwing on the axis of a boxplot;

```
boxplot(BA~Type, xlab = "Treatment Type", ylab= "Basal Area m"^"2")
```

How do i raise `m` to the power 2?

Thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736370/special-characters-and-superscripts-on-plot-axis-titles

Comment: Or see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156417/subscripts-in-plots-in-r ... try something like `ylab=expression("Basal Area m"^2)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subscripts in plots in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156417/subscripts-in-plots-in-r)